# How to pick effdt of the beginning row among consecutive rows?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a job record where emplid, effdt and status is there.
Now we have 4 types of status like A, L, P, S.

Now if we have consecutive rows of a single status then we have to pick the effdt of first row from where that status begin.

```
For Eg:
Emplid     Effdt    Status
100      4/4/2016    L
100     2/29/2016    L
100     12/25/2015   L
100     11/22/2015   A
100      9/22/2015   P
```

Here in the above example , for L status, i need to pick below row

```
Emplid   Effdt    Status
100    12/25/2015   L
```

thanks in Advance.

Comment: Read about `LEAD/LAG` window functions.

Comment: What if you have another row for the same emplid (100), status L, effdt of 5/15/2016? In that case what do you "need to pick"? Or is this simply picking the earliest date for a given status?

Answer (score 0):

You can group these using the "difference of row numbers" trick to get one row per employee and status in a sequence:

```
select emplid, status, min(effdt), max(effdt)
from (select t.*,
             (row_number() over (partition by emplid order by effdt) -
              row_number() over (partition by emplid, status order by effdt)
             ) as grp
      from t
     ) t
group by emplid, status, grp;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( emplid, effdt, status ) AS
SELECT 100, DATE '2016-04-04', 'L' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100, DATE '2016-02-29', 'L' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100, DATE '2015-12-25', 'L' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100, DATE '2015-11-22', 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 100, DATE '2015-09-22', 'P' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         CASE status
              WHEN LAG( status ) OVER ( PARTITION BY emplid ORDER BY effdt )
              THEN 0
              ELSE 1
              END AS has_changed
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  has_changed = 1;
```

**Output**:

```
EMPLID EFFDT      STATUS HAS_CHANGED
------ ---------- ------ -----------
   100 2015-09-22 P                1
   100 2015-11-22 A                1
   100 2015-12-25 L                1
```